# Creating Virtual Folders and hooking them into the file system

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, filesystems

I have a big collection of folders for projects I'm working on. I've been trying to find a better way to sort them all for a long time and I want to write an app that creates groups based on whatever criteria I say, such as "folders from 2011" or "folders containing a x type of file" etc.

This is fairly straightforward, and wouldn't present much of a problem to code using its own UI in winForms or WPF or something. But I think it would be far better if I could make these folders appear to be part of the filesystem, so other apps (like existing file explorers) can see them.

Is this possible? Would it cause problems I haven't considered? How do I go about doing it if it is possible?

One way I thought of doing it would be to have the app monitor the filesystem and create folder shortcuts every time there's a change, but I'm curious about whether its possible to actually present a fake filesystem to explorer through a 'gateway' folder

**EDIT:** Ok it's obviously possible since http://www.virtualfolder.net/ can do it, and now that I think of it so can **TrueCrypt**, although it would be nice if it didn't have to appear as a separate drive. So the question becomes, how do I implement it?

Comment: Windows 7 has that functionality built in

Answer (score 10):

You can create a [Shell Namespace Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521728.aspx) that gathers the file information you want and displays it within Windows Explorer any way you wish.  [You can choose where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096.aspx) your extension is located, whether as its own top-level node, a child of another system virtual folder/extension, or as a child of a file system folder.

Writing a SNE is not trivial, but it is a lot easier then writing a lower-level file system driver, and it does not require special driver-oriented compilers.  Any compiler that supports developing COM objects will work.

Answer (score 4):

This is accomplished using filesystem drivers or filesystem filter drivers. First let you create a virtual filesystem and mount it to a drive letter and also to a folder on NTFS drive (folder must exist but its contents are "replaced" with a virtual filesystem directory tree). Filesystem filter drivers let you introduce virtual files and folders in existing folders without replacing them.

VirtualFolder uses filesystem driver as it creates a drive letter.

Both types of drivers are written in C and work in kernel-mode. Writing them requires deep knowledge of Windows internals and experience with driver development (since filesystem drivers are one of the most complicated driver types).

We offer several products related to virtual storage. One of them, Callback File System, is a filesystem driver. It calls your user-mode code to perform actual filesystem functions. Another product, CallbackFilter, is an FS filter driver (and it also calls your user-mode code). However, current version of CallbackFilter doesn't let you introduce virtual files and folders (this would be implemented in the next release).

There's also Pismo File Mount product available, they use filter driver techniques. You can check with them if what you need can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you are looking for a way to present the results of predefined file queries to appear as though they are located at a specific location in the file system. If that is correct you may want to look into [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006.aspx). There are limits on what you can do with these file system services. However it is really straight forward to implement.